# SyncFramework deprovision scope leaves tracking records

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Sync Framework with parameters. First I provision template and then a scope with parameter ClientID.

Then my scenario is as following:

1. Provision specific scope for Client ABC.
2. Sync Client ABC.
3. Deprovision Client ABC and delete it from local DB (to keep local DB smaller).
4. After some time again I need that client in local DB. So I provision that client again.
5. Sync Client ABC. **SYNC FAILS.**

As I found at step 3 after I did deprovision for the client, the client record stayed in the tracking table. And when I deleted the client it marked it as sync_row_is_tombstone=1 because trigger is still there (I did not deprovision the template, I still need it).

My question why de-provision of the scope for the Client ABC leaved the Client ABC record in the tracking table? Am I doing something wrong or it is not designed to provision and deprovision a scope with specific parameter value?

Comment: how many scopes are referencing the table?

Comment: I have 300-400 scopes.

Comment: 300-400 scopes against the same table? change tracking is at table level, not scope level. if another scope is referencing the table, the tracking table will not be removed.